# Tomcat 7 went <defunct>, cannot kill the process. What might be the cause?

Tags: tomcat, java, tomcat7

I was running tomcat7 production server for several days, and then suddenly it was **unreachable** by the http port. Strangely though, the background processes **were still running** as can be seen by the logs.

So i tried to stop tomcat7 using `invoke-rc.d tomcat7 stop` from my *debian wheezy* box. But still the process is still there, with the  flag. I tried `kill -9 <pid>` and `killall -9 java`, but still the process is there - still occupying the port, causing me cannot start a new tomcat with the port is already used error.

I had to reboot. And everything is normal from there.

But i'm curious of what might cause this kind of situation ? There's no big loads whatsoever. Only some background processes running, scraping. I can see nothing suspicious from the logs.

What should i do if this happens again to get to the **real cause** and fix it ?

Here's my connector settings :

```
<Connector port="8080" address="127.0.0.1"
    maxParameterCount="500"
    maxPostSize="250000"
    scheme="http"
    secure="false"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    disableUploadTimeout="false"
    connectionUploadTimeout="300000"
    maxThreads="500"
    processorCache="500"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>
```

My tomcat version : **7.0.28-4+deb7u1**

My VM args :

> JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true
>   -Dspring.profiles.active="background,production" -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -javaagent:/var/lib/tomcat7/spring-instrument-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar -server -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/tomcat7/dump -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0 -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=10 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0 -XX:SurvivorRatio=256 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

jdk version : **7u60**

Comment: Have you already checked the `tomcat` logs?

Comment: @dawud: Yes i did, on the catalina*.log and all were my background processes' logs. But i also realized i hadnt checked the localhost*.log. They're gone now after i tried re-installing a backport version of the tomcat. I will be sure to check these files if it were to happen again. For now though, i'll stress test it.

Comment: Try to get a heap dump next time and/or a core dump. Maybe add some GC logging (e.g. via -Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat/gc.log). Also, latest Tomcat release is 7.0.55. Maybe look through release notes to see if update is warranted http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html.